# Postgres SQL for loop to count monthly existing users

Tags: sql

I have a users database for user sign up time:

```
id,  signup_time
100    2020-09-01
001    2018-01-01
....
```

How could I find monthly existing user  for all the history record? Use the last day in the month as the cut off day, existing users means if I observe in July last day, 2020-07-31, this user had already signed up before 2020-07-01. If I observe in June last day 2020-06-30, this user had already signed up before 2020-06-01.

Similar as a for loop in other language:

```
observation_year_month_list = ['2020-04','2020-05','2020-06']

 for i in observation_year_month_list:
      
     if user signup_time  < i:
        monthly_existing_user_count+1
```

Answer (score 1):

While [PL/SQL has loops](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS), that is a [procedural language extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming). SQL is a [declarative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) and does not use loops. Instead, you describe the results you want and the database comes up with a [query plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) to make it happen.

Your case is handled by [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) to aggregate rows into groups. In this case by month using [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC). Then you use the aggregate function [`count`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) to count up how many users are in each group.

```
select
  count(id) as num_users,
  date_trunc('month', signup_time) as signup_month
from users
group by date_trunc('month', signup_time)
```